# Angular Interface with Enum

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, enums, interface

is possible to have an interface with enum at angular ?

I have an interface like this:

```
export interface UserModel {
   title: TitleEnum
}
```

An Enum:

```
export enum TitleEnum {
    Admin = 0,
    Alfa = 1,
    Beta = 2
}
```

So I am trying to get {{user.title}}, keep receiving the numbers, am I missing something?

Comment: unfortunatelly this is how enum works, take a look here https://mariusschulz.com/blog/string-enums-in-typescript all the best

Answer (score 0):

This is how enums work! If you are looking assign the keys to strings, then you can use a string enum.

```js
export enum TitleEnum {
    Admin = 'Admin',
    Alfa = 'Alfa',
    Beta = 'Beta'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is to use a property

```
//in your component html
<select>
        <option *ngFor="let key of keys" [value]="key" [label]="race[key]"></option>
</select>


export enum RaceCodeEnum {
    Asian = 1,
    Mexican = 2,
    AfricanAmerican = 3,
    White = 4,

}

export class RaceSelect {

  race= RaceCodeEnum;

  constructor() {
    this.keys = Object.keys(this.race).filter(k => !isNaN(Number(k)));
  }
}
```